# Minimum number of bits required to encode a subset of sequences of length 200

Tags: information-theory

The typical set $S$ is given as consisting of all sequences $x$ with at most three 1s.

Here $x \in ${0,1}$ ^{200} $ and $P(0) = 0.99$

We can use $\log_{2}|S|$ to encode such sequences. And that is the best one can do in case of equal length codewords I think.

But how to get the minimum *expected* no. of bits required for encoding the sequences in $S$ ?

Should I think in terms of the ceil of the entropy of the least probable one of these sequences times the number of such sequences?

Comment: You should compute the number of sequences in $S$.  You then need to pick one out of those, which you can do in $\log_2 |S|$ bits.  You may need to find a mapping from the strings of $\log_2 |S|$ bits to the sequences in $S$.  I don't think it is clear whether that is required.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can I do better( lesser) than $\log_2 |S|$ bits in the encoding scheme ?

Comment: No, you can't.  You should recognize that $n$  bits give you $2^n$ sequences, so can specify one in $2^n$.  The formula computes that $n$

Comment: @RossMillikan Even not for differing codeword lengths? Can I use something like Huffman coding here?

Comment: We haven't talked of codewords here at all.  You have a list of possible strings.  If there were $1024$ of them, you could use $10$ bit strings to indicate one of them.  It doesn't matter what the lengths of the $1024$ strings are, just how many of them there are.  In your problem, all the strings of $S$ are the same length, $100$ bits.  The strings used to indicate one of them will also have the same length (within $1$ if the log doesn't come out evenly).

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes yes, I understand that.

Comment: I am wondering if I can reduce the expected/ average length of the codewords assigned to each of these sequences under some scheme.

Comment: No, the $\log_2 |S|$ assumes you use them perfectly.  Nothing can be better.  To do that, you have to know $S$ in advance because you are just making a one-to-one correspondence.  Huffman coding and the others assume you do not know $S$ in advance.  They are less efficient in terms of bits stored, not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have specified you were interested in minimizing the *expected* codeword length. Lets look at arbitrary $n,$ and consider $\{0,1\}^n.$

In that case you can assign a 1 bit codeword, say $0$, to the all zero sequence which has probability ($p=P(0)$)
$$
p^n,
$$
In general, you can specify all weight $w$ codewords with
$$
W_w = \left\lceil \log_2 \binom{n}{w}\right\rceil
$$
bits for $w=1,2,3.$
You have 4 classes of typical sequences $W_0,W_1,W_2,W_3$ and you can specify which class you have with a prefix of 2 bits [note for $p=0.99$ there may be a slightly more efficient use of the prefix but I don't think so since $.99^{200}$ is already a small number]. For the all zero codeword just use the prefix 00 and no extra bits are necessary.

So there exists a good code with small expected codeword length
$$
\overline{L}=2+\sum_{w=1}^3 W_w \binom{n}{w} p^{(n-w)}(1-p)^w.
$$

Using $\log_2 |S|$ I get 20.347 bits are needed so 21 bits are needed.

The expectation above is approximately 9.64 bits so you can get an expected codeword length of 10+2=12 bits, if I have calculated correctly (please check).

Comment: Yes, checked it. Thanks !